# What sensor to use to track human presence outside of a room from inside

Tags: sensor, programming, sound, pir

I would like to track human presence (or could also be sound). I will place these sensors inside my room and should be able to track these events outside of my room.

The door of my room is in-front of another door. I want to track if a person enters or exits that door (through sound or whatever). The catch is I want to do this from inside. The distance between the doors is just 1 meter. And the sound of the both doors can be heard from both sides when they are opened.

Comment: "_Also could you advice what specific sensor ..._". No. See [Don't ask](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Now if you were to ask 'what type(s) of sensor might help me achieve this', you may not be in danger of having  the question closed.

Answer (score 1):

Microwave.

It can penetrate a lot of materials, but not all. Depends on what the room is made of. Search for microwave detector.

There will be a detection field, some are adjustable.

You will likely then need to integrate to a microcontroller/microprocessor for WiFi and website.

Doubt there is anything off the shelf that will do what you want.

That's enough to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Bman,
You can use PIR sensor, which works on hot body radiation detection or else also you can use IR sensor.

Comment: hi will this work if I put it inside the room and monitor something outside?

Comment: It seems that @bman wants to detect **through** a wall, which PIR will not typically do.  A very good (and expensive) IR sensor might.